# Will any python code that run in idle have access to all installed ram?

Tags: python, ram, python-idle, channel

I don't mind slow computing but lack of memory crashed my computer on some program runs.

Will any Python IDLE program be able to access all installed RAM and use it if neccessary?

Comment: By "python programs that run in idle" do you mean programs that don't actually do anything, or programs run in the IDLE IDE?

Comment: Idle ide. Runned, mostly for graphics and sometimes just numbers and graphs

Comment: Wait, what happened to all the text in your question?

Comment: Running a python program with python from the IDLE editor instead of directly with python uses at most a few extra megabytes, which is nearly nothing compared the the gigabytes on any modern machine.  So IDLE is almost irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Oh ... you're mixing a lot of concepts which you haven't fully understood.

> I'm considering buying a new computer (my old is kaput).

If it's broken, you should either have it repaired or buy a new one.

> it was explained to me how that by default the program run in one thread unless written for more threads.

Python programs will run on one thread because of the GIL (global interpreter lock), that's true. If you want more CPUs to be used, you need to use the `multiprocessing` library.

> I don't mind slow computing but lack of memory brought some program runs to a hault [sic]

I assume that you mean *halt*.

I doubt that this is possible. Programs can become really slow if there's not enough physical RAM, maybe by a factor of 1000. The reason is that RAM will be swapped to disk and that operation takes much longer. But it should not stop completely.

> "Will for example four dual channel RAMs work with Python programs that run in IDLE?" Is what I've been contemplating.

Yes and no. Python does not have direct access to physical RAM. The operating system provides virtual RAM to an application. Typically, if there's no other reason against it, the operating system will give physical RAM. Therefore yes, more physical RAM will typically increase the physical RAM available for Python programs.

> Will any Python IDLE program be able to access all installed RAM and use it if necessary?

No. For example, 32 Bit Python will only be able to address a subset. But even with 64 Bit Python, some memory will be reserved for the operating system.

> could have been computed and stored in stages

To answer that, we would need to know what you are computing and how much memory that will need. Typically, the memory need can be computed. The Big-O notation does that. And typically you can compensate RAM for CPU and vice versa.

> Is it possible to have enough computing power if there is enough time and drive space?

For some tasks, there is never enough computing power, e.g. brute force password cracking. Again, we would need to know what you are attempting to calculate.

How to procede?

First of all, it would be good to know your PC specs. How many CPU cores and how much RAM do you have? Second, a look at task manager shows how much RAM is in use, cached and free?

It's quite likely that CPU is mostly idle (as you said, it's only 1 of maybe 8). It's also quite likely that your RAM is still free. In such a case, your algorithm is just crappy, e.g. stuck in an endless loop.

Learn about the difference between physical RAM and virtual RAM. Talk in the correct terms. Learn how to measure both. Then come back with the numbers and the source code.

BTW: what is actually kaput with your computer? And how did you diagnose that? If your computer is just not doing what you think it should do, maybe it's simply a bug in the program.

Comment: First, thank you! I will look at virtual and physical ram. Kaput as in I gently through it down to the floor, smashed. The program im writing does graphics by trigonometry through imaginary funnels that are boundaries for 3d equations superpositioned and proccesed 2d for 3d image. Basically a 3d graph with shading and distortion that in photography is called lensing. The program is a bunch of lists. I dont know how to reprocate minimal code for same result. Program wont fit stack exchange + 1000 lines of code. Thanks again for giving me something to search for

Comment: @Progrmmingisfun: phew. I have no domain knowledge in what you're doing, so I can't even give a rough estimate. How long are your lists? How many lists do you process? What is the data type in the list?

Comment: @Progrmmingisfun: For a few tool, have a look at SysInternals Process Explorer, SysInternals VMMap and SysInternals RAMMap. Maybe buy the book "SysInternals Administrator's Reference" by Mark Russinovich. If you're a serious programmer, that'll give you tons of insights and many other useful tools. Even I knew most of the tools, the book was worth buying.